# Having trouble to add markers on current location

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, google-maps-markers

i making a custom android maps using google maps api v2. I wanted to put a marker on user current location.my code is:

```
// Enabling MyLocation in Google Map
    getMap().setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    // BY THIS YOU CAN CHANGE MAP TYPE
    // mGoogleMap.setMapType(mGoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);

    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            // First get location from Network Provider
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    Currentloc = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (Currentloc != null) {
                        onLocationChanged(Currentloc);
                        latitude = Currentloc.getLatitude();
                        longitude = Currentloc.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (Currentloc == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        Currentloc = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (Currentloc != null) {
                            onLocationChanged(Currentloc);
                            latitude = Currentloc.getLatitude();
                            longitude = Currentloc.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

    // double lat = Currentloc.getLatitude();
    // double lng = Currentloc.getLongitude();

    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    // Setting the position for the marker
    markerOptions.position(latLng);

    // Setting the title for the marker.
    // This will be displayed on taping the marker
    markerOptions.title("ADD IMAGE?");
    // markerOptions.snippet("ADD IMAGE?");

    // Placing a marker on the touched position
    getMap().addMarker(markerOptions);
    getMap().setOnMarkerClickListener((OnMarkerClickListener) this);
```

and OnLocationChanged code is

```
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    mLongitude = location.getLongitude();
    // LatLng latLng = new LatLng(mLatitude, mLongitude);
    //markerOptions.notify();

    //getMap().addMarker(markerOptions);
    getMap().moveCamera(
            CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(
                    location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())));
    getMap().animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));

}
```

My program running there is no error. But my problem is the line

```
getMap().setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

given me a blue pointer in map on the user current location And i manually add a markers on the user curent location(AS THE CODE ABOVE).My marker and blue pointer have to be the same location because they describe same loc(same latitude and longitude) BUT they are not.After run my code the output is look like this image
https://www.dropbox.com/s/argxzb1fnarzie4/Screenshot_2014-11-05-02-43-06.png?dl=0
My question is according to my code they need to same position but why not? How can i add marker at the same position of the blue pointer.
Thnanks in advance

Comment: Why comment this in OnLocationChanged(Location location) //getMap().addMarker(markerOptions);

Answer (score 0):

First thing I'll try is moving the lines of code below inside the onLocationChanged()

```
  markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

// double lat = Currentloc.getLatitude();
// double lng = Currentloc.getLongitude();

LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

// Setting the position for the marker
markerOptions.position(latLng);

// Setting the title for the marker.
// This will be displayed on taping the marker
markerOptions.title("ADD IMAGE?");
// markerOptions.snippet("ADD IMAGE?");

// Placing a marker on the touched position
getMap().addMarker(markerOptions);
```

Comment: i try but it does the same , no change @jucas

Answer (score 0):

I think its because your currentLocation is the last known location. See what happens if you set the currentLocation to

```
Currentloc = getMap().getMyLocation()
```

Comment: bro when i set this my app crashes because of null pointer exception @David Zafrani

Comment: What class is the class you're performing the call from extending?